# Tag synonym: polar-coordinates | spherical-coordinates

Tags: discussion, tag-management

I feel the tags [polar-coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polar-coordinates) and [spherical-coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spherical-coordinates) should be merged to general $n$-dimensional polar coordinates, since [polar-coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polar-coordinates) is used for the general anyways.

Comment: Huh? I apparently never got the memo that "polar coordinates" is "used for general anyways". I always reserve that term for two dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

I am not convinced. Those are separate topics in calculus. For a typical calculus student asking questions on either of these topics, "$n$-dimensional polar coordinates" could as well be in Greek. Besides, "$n$-dimensional polar coordinates" does not fit the 25 character limit.

If the tags are indeed merged, I'd rather merge all them into [coordinate-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-systems), which is short and understandable.

Comment: As to the character limit: how about n-dim-polar-coordinates; or simply leave polar-coordinates and adjust the description to include any dimension (especially spherical)

Comment: Could be a language thing. Where I come from, Polarkoordinaten is the common term. Very rarely, in dimension $3$, some people speak (write) of sphärische Polarkoordinaten, I don't remember having seen that used in dimensions $> 3$, though. From that perspective, I don't understand the singling out of the two-dimensional case in the English nomenclature. But meh.